$dispatch() event in Alpine.js is called twice
I am working on the livewire/Alpine project. I have a alpine blade as following :
<div class="tile-container" x-data="{
    tiles: Array(28).fill().map((_, idx) => idx),
  
   animate(key) {
    $dispatch('showMe', { info: key });
   }
                  
}">

<template x-for="(tile, index) in tiles" :key="index">
    <div class="tile" :id="'tile-' + index"
       x-on:click="animate(index)">
       </div>
  </template>

</div>

in my component I am listening the event and can see that the event has been dispatched twice at the same time. I checked the network tab and I see that the dispatch event has been fired twice :
[
    {
        "path": "",
        "method": "__dispatch",
        "params": [
            "showeMe",
            {
                "info": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "",
        "method": "__dispatch",
        "params": [
            "showeMe",
            {
                "info": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]

I need this approach because I am having private variable where I need to maintain the state of this variable. if I use $wire.call then the state of private variable is not being preserved. I have tried almost all, but no success. if I use Livewire.dispatch instead it is not being called twice but this time again, I can't store my private variable state due to the new instance of each call. Any help would be highly appreciated.

How have you installed Alpine.js? What versions are you using?

I have not installed the alpine manually, but it has been installed while I install the livewire.. the version is : 3.13.0 which is default version of livewire when it has been installed. I also used to run window.Alpine command to see if there are multiple alpine instances, but no, there is only single instance but multiple dispatch events.

To generate a network call the event will be received backend side I assume, can you show the class?

it is nothing with class I think, because the problem happens in the client side, $dispatch event is triggered twice as browser console logs confirm this as well.

I have copied this code snippet into my own project running Livewire 3 and I only have a singular click event. Are you certain there isn't an extra click being triggered?
